# Is an F-Gas certificate required to operate an automatic Aircon charging machine? (UK)

Tags: ac

In the UK is it required by law for an operator in for example a local garage, to hold an "F-Gas" certificate in order to operate a fully automatic air conditioning refrigerant refilling machine?

I know it is a requirement for manual refilling manifolds etc.

Comment: The main reason for certification in refrigeration service is to reduce/eliminate discharging known refrigerants that contributes to depleting the ozone layer that protects humans from harmful ultraviolet light from the sun. Dealers and repair shops make up the majority of ac service/repairs so they're required to be trained in proper reclamation procedures removing refrigerant before repairs are made. UK regulations; https://www.gov.uk/guidance/qualifications-required-to-work-on-equipment-containing-f-gas. Refrigerants with fluorocarbons; https://www.gov.uk/guidance/fluorinated-gases-f-gases

Comment: @FDryer - Is that an answer? please post as an answer not comment. 
(Its also not very conclusive)

Comment: My comment is meant to help with info as the links provide definitions of UK certifications separating diyers from working mechanics and technicians in vehicle services.